# Accessing private data on google cloud storage

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gdal, mapserver

I am using Google Cloud to set up a map server. The goal is to serve private images that are broken into tiles and stored into subdirectories of the format z/x/y where z is the zoom level, x is the horizontal axis and y is the vertical axis. I want to be able to access those tiles through LabelBox (https://support.labelbox.com/docs/tiled-imagery), but in order to do so i have to upload a json file that contains the tile layer URL, which is private and unable to access. What can i do to access those files through LabelBox? I am attaching the example json file on LabelBox's website:

```
    [{
      "tileLayerUrl": "https://public-tiles.dronedeploy.com/1499994155_DANIELOPENPIPELINE_ortho_qfs/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJsaWMtdGlsZXMuZHJvbmVkZXBsb3kuY29tLzE0OTk5OTQxNTVfREFOSUVMT1BFTlBJUEVMSU5FX29ydGhvX3Fmcy8qIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoyMTQ1OTE0MTE4fX19XX0_&Signature=O~50rrGXdEC6Hi8jPJ3dbT~UtBd7Cw6iQPTxdJ8LU2IaoxeP22R3JpKPkLN3T3~Lcw3CyX7uft2Baj0MH93qUoCYyN~~jNX3OMkYV2jbrHDezf6zQRHAabXX-L2bL-JEGfFL6z3DWccOFeCH56CuhgC29k5CJx7I34P-LQJdnAUsA-KaqKH1IyYsHStRIfmMzdXNAWU58FTfqVljq9SbKXxfgdr2SZ~7VgLaZ8IhA0WnlKUo-JgqTd~jYa5mGCpR8351IMK0aMuY4Mld4SOXssQ-rOtlZtypvo8FDp474TlGIEGz5PHxGOPsqLPF19hEYTgoPqsUj8QEuiTfg-cmsg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJXGC45PGQXCMCXSA",
      "bounds": [
          [
              37.86857121694444,
              -122.32616227416666
          ],
          [
              37.87676075527778,
              -122.31316180916666
          ]
      ],
      "minZoom": 10,
      "maxZoom": 23,
      "epsg": "EPSG4326"
      },{
     "tileLayerUrl": "https://public-tiles.dronedeploy.com/1499994155_DANIELOPENPIPELINE_ortho_qfs/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9wdWJsaWMtdGlsZXMuZHJvbmVkZXBsb3kuY29tLzE0OTk5OTQxNTVfREFOSUVMT1BFTlBJUEVMSU5FX29ydGhvX3Fmcy8qIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IkRhdGVMZXNzVGhhbiI6eyJBV1M6RXBvY2hUaW1lIjoyMTQ1OTE0MTE4fX19XX0_&Signature=O~50rrGXdEC6Hi8jPJ3dbT~UtBd7Cw6iQPTxdJ8LU2IaoxeP22R3JpKPkLN3T3~Lcw3CyX7uft2Baj0MH93qUoCYyN~~jNX3OMkYV2jbrHDezf6zQRHAabXX-L2bL-JEGfFL6z3DWccOFeCH56CuhgC29k5CJx7I34P-LQJdnAUsA-KaqKH1IyYsHStRIfmMzdXNAWU58FTfqVljq9SbKXxfgdr2SZ~7VgLaZ8IhA0WnlKUo-JgqTd~jYa5mGCpR8351IMK0aMuY4Mld4SOXssQ-rOtlZtypvo8FDp474TlGIEGz5PHxGOPsqLPF19hEYTgoPqsUj8QEuiTfg-cmsg__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJXGC45PGQXCMCXSA",
     "bounds": [
          [
              37.86857121694444,
              -122.32616227416666
          ],
          [
              37.87676075527778,
              -122.31316180916666
          ]
     ],
     "minZoom": 10,
     "maxZoom": 23,
     "epsg": "EPSG4326"
   }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). This will generate an URL with a key pointing to the objects or bucket, with this you can access the data outside of GCP without making it public.

You can find the relavant article on LabelBox [site](https://support.labelbox.com/docs/cloud-data).